# can't access monero wallet or run a node

Tags: monerod

Hey guys i bought monero back in the summer and haven't touched it since, my wallet on the monero cli has my stash of monero but i cannot access it because i can't run monerod program on the command line. i get this error
RUNNING MAC OS el capitan 10.11.6 and the version before it. (i just updated..)

heres the error i get:

> > 2016-Nov-19 02:38:42.802560 Loading blockchain from folder /Users/won/.bitmonero/lmdb ... 2016-Nov-19 02:38:42.802647 option: fastest 2016-Nov-19 02:38:42.802668 option: async 2016-Nov-19 02:38:42.802684 option: 1000 Segmentation fault: 11

Does anyone know how to trouble shoot this? I just downloaded the latest version and tried running monerod too and same result. The monero cli wallet used to ask me my wallet name which i don't know. I do have my passphrase password so im good i guess. Can anyone give some advice on troubleshooting this?? thanks ahead of time!

Comment: You should consider writing up a response describing what was wrong and how you fixed it.  Then mark that answer as the best answer.  It otherwise appears this question is unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that it was in the .bitmonero directory. i just copied and pasted everything there in that directory to be safe and deleted the directory.  Then i downloaded the latest zip file from moneros site and ran monerod again and it worked. @barrystyle I guess you were correct thank you!

> "There was a hardfork about 2 months ago (hardfork v3); this would be why (more than likely). I'm guessing that your old version has continued past the hardfork blockheight, without it knowing, and you are on an invalid chain." - barrystyle